# Add shortcut to taskbar corner icons

Tags: taskbar, icons

I've researched the hell out of this and have no idea how it's done. I made a custom script to connect and disconnect from my bluetooth headphones. I'd love for there to a way to put these on the taskbar corner icons list. somehow.

How can I add a shortcut to the little taskbar icons in the corner?

Comment: Your question, as it is currently written, is just a collection of statements. Please edit it according to [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and the help section in general.

Comment: My bad, was tired when I made this post :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Taskbar Corner Icons" is technically the "System Tray Area" or "System Notification Area".

Windows has no "Direct Way" to add "Short Cuts" there , & uses that Area to show Notifications & Status Messages or to show Icons for Applications which are registered to show there.

Notifications & Status Messages : We can see Printer Status , USB Device Status , Speaker Volume , Etc.

Applications which are registered to show there : There are various tools like Dictionary (WordWeb) , AntiVirus (Windows Defender) , Torrent Sharing (Azureus) , Etc which register themselves to show Icons there.

Hence , to get what you require , you must Either (1) make your own Programming to show some Icon there OR (2) use third Party tools which will register themselves there & then let you configure various actions to Perform when-ever you require.

Here are some such Solutions :

With Own Programming [ not very Simple to use , Completely Customizable ] :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3327/System-Tray-Icons

Using third Party tools [ Simple to use , not Completely Customizable ] :
https://www.blacksunsoftware.com/flashtray.html
https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TrayStart.shtml

If you have your Custom Commands to Connect+DisConnect Bluetooth Devices , you should put that in Custom Scripts , then use the third Party tools to Execute those Scripts when you navigate onto those "Quick Launch" Icons.

With your Own Programming , you can have your own actions & your own hotkeys &  your own Icons to show the Current Status , whether Connected or DisConnected , Etc.

Comment: I love this, thank you. Should be neough to either get me started, or raise more questions XD

Comment: btw I am thinking of making a program for the task bar which will list out paired usb devices and allow easy connecting/disconnectin the way mac has in their menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts: Right-click a shortcut and select "Pin to taskbar." For example, if you want to open a Notepad document, right-click notepad.exe and select "Pin to taskbar."

Comment: I mean the little icons in the corner next to the time and date. SUrely there's a way I can add something there

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded windows insider 22h2 and the latest updates and I don't have a need for this anymore, however the answer by Prem is still really helpful if you want to do this.

All I wanted was a bluetooth menu like mac has, an now finally window has it if you sign up for the insider beta channel.